# Onsen UI Tabbar + Carousel combine

Tags: carousel, onsen-ui, tabbar

I try to combine Tabbar + Carousel for a drag effect with Onsen UI

I have a little problem ;

When I add the Tabbar in the same page as the carousel, the carousel swipe does not work.

And when I put the tabbar in a different page of the carousel the swipe works well but I can not retrieve the current index (OnPostChange)

Someone has the solution please?

Thank you

I put the two codes that do not work below

First :
https://codepen.io/yohann3396/pen/brppxY

Second :
https://codepen.io/yohann3396/pen/jLqqdK

```
 ons.bootstrap();
  ons.ready(function() {

 alert('test');
  carousel.on('postchange', function(event) {
  var test = carousel.getActiveIndex();
  alert(test);
  });


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in the current version. I'm sorry nobody answered you, I've been struggling to find a solution.

There is a workaround for a simple site. If you make a complete duplicate carousel for every tab, then you can change the page value to a distinct name. You must have a page for every tab, and you may not use duplicates, but you can link to a specific page in a carousel. The user wouldn't be able to tell they are actually on a separate carousel with a distinct template ID if you duplicate all of them.